# Given large data.table, use binary search to find the correct row based on the first two columns and then add 1 to third column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 3 columns. First two columns are IDs (ID1 and ID2) referring to the same item and the third column is a count of how many times items with these two IDs appear. The dataframe has many rows so I want to use binary search to first find the appropriate row where both IDs match and then add 1 to the cell under the count column in that row.

I have used the `which()` function to find the index of the correct row and then using the index added 1 to the count column.

For example:

```
index <- which(DF$ID1 == x & DF$ID1 == y)

DF$Count[index] <- DF$Count[index] + 1
```

While this works, the which function is very inefficient. Because I have to do this within a for loop for more than a trillion times, it takes a lot of time. Also, there is only one row in the data frame with this ID combination. While the which function goes through all the rows, a function that stops once it finds the correct row should suffice. I have looked into using `data.table` and `setkey` for this purpose but do not know how to implement that for my purpose. Thank you in advance.

Comment: May be you need to provide an example and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed you can use `data.table` and `setkeyv` (not `setkey` because you need 2 columns as indexes)

```
library(data.table)

DF <- data.frame(ID1=sample(1:100,100000,replace=TRUE),ID2=sample(1:100,100000,replace=TRUE))
# convert DF to a data.table
DF <- as.data.table(DF)
# put both ID1 and ID2 as indexes, in that order
setkeyv(DF,c("ID1","ID2"))
# random x and y values
x <- 10
y <- 18
# select value for ID1=x and ID2=y and add 1 in the Count column
DF[.(x,y),"Count"] <-  DF[,.(x,y),"Count"]+1
```